# I'm busy making a gameshow game asking random questions, and giving the player an option of 4 answers

Tags: javascript

But im struggling to assign the random questions to the main class(gameshow)

```
else if(state.getCurrentScreen() == Screens.in_game){

    util.getQuestion();
    if(a == 0){
        console.log("Correct!");
    }
    else{
        console.log("Wrong!");
    }

}
```

this is the `util.getQuestion()` class

```
getQuestion(){
    if(i<randQuestions.length){
        console.log(randQuestions[i]);
        console.log(json[i]["answers"]);

    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: where does the i in getQuestion come from?

Comment: What is i in your code. Is it random number or looping variable?

Comment: We need to know where you're getting i from.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, i is a variable i declare up in the program and assign a value to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use below code:

I am assuming that you have an array with name randomQuestions.

```
var a= Math.floor(Math.random() * randQuestions.length))
console.log(randQuestions[a]);
```

Comment: that's my mistake